# Calculating relative velocity in three dimensional space

Tags: kinematics, velocity, vectors, relative-motion, galilean-relativity

Given two points $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ whose position and velocity vectors are, respectively:
$$\mathbf{r_A}=\begin{pmatrix}r_{A_{x}}\\r_{A_{y}}\\r_{A_{z}}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{r_B}=\begin{pmatrix}r_{B_{x}}\\r_{B_{y}}\\r_{B_{z}}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{v_A}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{A_{x}}\\v_{A_{y}}\\v_{A_{z}}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{v_B}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{B_{x}}\\v_{B_{y}}\\v_{B_{z}}\end{pmatrix}$$
[image]
How would you calculate the relative velocity of $\mathcal{A}$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ and the opposite, given random position and velocity?

*For example*: if the two points are moving in the same direction, you would calculate the velocity of $\mathcal{A}$ relative to $\mathcal{B}$ with the following formula:
$$\mathbf{v_{AB}}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{A_{x}}\\v_{A_{y}}\\v_{A_{z}}\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}v_{B_{x}}\\v_{B_{y}}\\v_{B_{z}}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{A_{x}}-v_{B_{x}}\\v_{A_{y}}-v_{B_{y}}\\v_{A_{z}}-v_{B_{z}}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Your question is strange because in the example at the bottom you give the correct answer. I do not see what your question is I'm afraid. (+1 though for setting your question out so neatly with a good diagram.)

Comment: Does the last formula also work when the two velocities are not collinear?

Comment: Ok I think I might see your question now...

Comment: Thank you and sorry for not making it clear in the first place.

Comment: No problem - I hope the answer is clear - if not comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for the $\mathbf{v_{AB}}$, the velocity of $\mathcal{A}$ relative to $\mathcal{B}$ with the following formula is correct and general for all 'real' values of  $v_{X_{i}}$ where $X=A, B$ and $i=x, y, z$.

$$\mathbf{v_{AB}}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{A_{x}}\\v_{A_{y}}\\v_{A_{z}}\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}v_{B_{x}}\\v_{B_{y}}\\v_{B_{z}}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}v_{A_{x}}-v_{B_{x}}\\v_{A_{y}}-v_{B_{y}}\\v_{A_{z}}-v_{B_{z}}\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that the velocities will only be collinear if $\mathbf{v_{A} \times v_{B}} = \mathbf{0}$, which cannot be assumed for random values.

Final note is that this is not correct for particles moving at speeds close to the speed of light, where special relativity will give a better picture.

Comment: So if _for example_ **vA** = (0, 12, 0) (going all the way to the positive y semiaxis) and **vB** = (-5, -5, 0) (following the bisector of the negative x and y semiplane),  is it correct to calculate **vAB** this way? **vAB** = (0, 12, 0) - (-5, -5, 0) = (0 - [-5], 12 - [-5], 0 - 0) = (5, 17, 0).

Comment: yes that is correct :-)